# iOS touch event notifications (private API)

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

It's possible to [simulate touch events on iOS](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html), and you can receive various system wide notifications when in the background using CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver and CFNotificationCenterAddObserver, eg:

- [IOS Jailbreak How do intercept SMS / Text Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680764/ios-jailbreak-how-do-intercept-sms-text-messages)
- [How can I detect screen lock/unlock events on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888490/how-can-i-detect-screen-lock-unlock-events-on-the-iphone)

I've yet to find a way to get touch notifications while in the background though. Is there a "touch event" that can be used with CFNotificationCenterAddObserver, a different notification center that can be used, or a completely different approach?

I'd be happy with low level touch information (eg. x, y coordinates and touch type), but higher level information (eg. key pressed, back button pressed etc) would be even better!

Comment: Perhaps this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303235/is-it-possible-to-capture-touch-events-in-the-background-on-a-jailbroken-ios-dev. Also do a search for `GSEvents`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the IOHID stuff in **IOKit** to get the x, y coordinates.

```
#include <IOHIDEventSystem.h>
```

create IOHIDEventSystemClient:

```
void *ioHIDEventSystem = IOHIDEventSystemClientCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
```

register callback:

```
IOHIDEventSystemClientScheduleWithRunLoop(ioHIDEventSystem, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
IOHIDEventSystemClientRegisterEventCallback(ioHIDEventSystem, handle_event, NULL, NULL);
```

unregister callback:

```
IOHIDEventSystemClientUnregisterEventCallback(ioHIDEventSystem, handle_event, NULL, NULL);
IOHIDEventSystemClientUnscheduleWithRunLoop(ioHIDEventSystem, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
```

callback:

```
void handle_event (void* target, void* refcon, IOHIDServiceRef service, IOHIDEventRef event) {
   if (IOHIDEventGetType(event)==kIOHIDEventTypeDigitizer){
       IOHIDFloat x=IOHIDEventGetFloatValue(event, (IOHIDEventField)kIOHIDEventFieldDigitizerX);
       IOHIDFloat y=IOHIDEventGetFloatValue(event, (IOHIDEventField)kIOHIDEventFieldDigitizerY);
       int width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
       int height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
       NSLog(@"click : %f, %f", x*width, y*height) ;
   }
}
```

Also, you can check this out: 
[IOHIDEventSystemCreate on iOS6 failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354240/iohideventsystemcreate-on-ios6-failed).
Hope this helps.

EDIT: Please see the result from the log. Tested on iPhone 4 and 5.

```
void handle_event (void* target, void* refcon, IOHIDServiceRef service, IOHIDEventRef event) {
    NSLog(@"handle_event : %d", IOHIDEventGetType(event));
if (IOHIDEventGetType(event)==kIOHIDEventTypeDigitizer){
    IOHIDFloat x=IOHIDEventGetFloatValue(event, (IOHIDEventField)kIOHIDEventFieldDigitizerX);
    IOHIDFloat y=IOHIDEventGetFloatValue(event, (IOHIDEventField)kIOHIDEventFieldDigitizerY);
    NSLog(@" x %f : y %f", x, y);
//2013-03-28 10:02:52.169 MyIOKit[143:907] handle_event : 11
//2013-03-28 10:02:52.182 MyIOKit[143:907]  x 0.766754 : y 0.555023
}
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm getting the events, but my x,y values are enormous, eg: 1050201600.000000, 1052667392.000000. Any tips?

Comment: Have you checked x and y before multiplying? I am not in front of my Mac now but as far as I remember I got x and y in from of %. Eg if you touch around the top right corner, x = 0.9 and y 0.1.

Comment: Yeah the huge number is the x,y without multiplying.

Comment: OK. I'll get back to you when I have a mac.

Comment: On iOS6 I'm seeing the huge values still, eg: x 1064502784.000000 : y 1034551296.000000 :(

Comment: @BenDowling This is weird. I did test on iOS6.

Comment: Just downloaded your test project and built that and that does work exactly how you've described, so it must just be a problem with the code in my project - will dig into it. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Good to hear that. Good luck!

Comment: It gives me error that 'IOHIDEventSystem.h' file not found ... any idea ?

Comment: But how can capture multi touch events?

Comment: Does anybody got the answer for this question? I need to inject system wide touch in iOS8. I have already asked similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915920/ios8-touch-injection-programatically but nobody replied to it. I really need answer asap.