# iOS run application when phone rings

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

Is there any way to create an iOS application that launches and a call is received (basically hijacking the call receive event). Then the application can (after having done what it needs to do - maybe after a second or two), allow the user to answer and continue normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope it is not possible to interfere the call mechanism ,may be there will be some way in jaibreak option

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK that is not possible , but you can have a look at [CoreTelephony](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html).

in the docs it says

> A CTCall object gives you information about a current call, including
>   a unique identifier and state information—dialing, incoming,
>   connected, or disconnected.

may be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a answer but a direction. Through IOHID(private API) your application can stay in background. It can monitor all hardware events like network or touch events. When a call is received, it would call back your application which is in background. I have a feeling that phone calls would also generate a call back which you can then handle.

Here is the sample code https://github.com/entryleveldev/TestIOHIDEvent. Also read this answer 
[iOS touch event notifications (private API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537564/ios-touch-event-notifications-private-api)

I have personally done it for touch events and it works pretty well in background. You can put a NSLog and monitor all types of events and easily figure out if phone calls generate a call back or not. If not, I am having a feeling that there might be other private API out there to help.

Drawback is, if you use private api, you app will get rejected in app store. Good luck.

Edit: This solution does not require jail breaking. Only use of private API.