# How to listen all touch events on a jailbreak ios device even the app is running in background

Tags: ios, events, device, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

I want to know how can I listen all touch events on a jailbreak ios device even the app is running in background. This feature was implemented in an app named AutoTouch. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post the code and explain the exact problem you have.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to capture system wide touch events just by private api without jailbreaking (ofcourse it will work on jailbroken device too).. Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537564/ios-touch-event-notifications-private-api/). It also contains link to github example.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the libactivator, the standard tool on jailbreaked iDevices to handle touchevents -> https://github.com/rpetrich/libactivator