# Getting refrence of current touch event similar to VoiceOver

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-privateapi, voiceover

I am developing an iphone app for my internal purpose(dont want to put it on App Store).
I want Some functionality similar to built in VoiceOver Application in iPhone.

In my app, i want my app to be kept in background, and when user touches to any button,textfield or any UIElement, then my backgrounded app should be able to know the accessibility label of that element which was touched by User and then perform some action(similar to speech in voiceover). Is there any private apis available to get this detail. If it is possible for jailbroken, then still it is OK for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use IOHid framework to do this.

Look at this question, because it has the code how to do this:
[iOS touch event notifications (private API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537564/ios-touch-event-notifications-private-api)

Although, I am not sure this method is still applicable in iOS 7 (I believe it was discussed in iOS 6 timeframe).

Comment: Hii, i have seen the link provided by you, i got how to get touch location(the x and y coordinates), but i actually require, what is under that touch location, i.e. is it button or textfield etc?

Comment: Oh... you actually need to get a control (vs just a coordinate). I am not aware of a known method to do this on non jailbrokend iPhone.BTW I spent quite a lot of time on VoiceOver and found that it's protected by entitlements, so I can't get what I want on jailed device.

Comment: k, no problem, i got something after r & d, i will share it if it will  work fine